# QSpinbox Check if up or down button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there a simple way to check if the up or down button of a QT spinbox is pressed? I've seen this in a forum on QT but don't know how to deconstruct it or is far complex for me to understand and I'm coding in PyQT5.

```
void MySpinBox::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)

QSpinBox::mousePressEvent(event);

QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
this->initStyleOption(&opt);

if( this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp).contains(event->pos()) )
    // UP BUTTON PRESSED
else if( this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_SpinBoxDown).contains(event->pos()) )
    //DOWN BUTTON PRESSED
```

Also I have this 2 variables that contain the spinbox value

```
version_spinValue = self.ui.version_sbox.value()
work_spinValue = self.ui.work_sbox.value()
```

All I want to do is when the version value spinbox up button is pressed, the work spinbox value resets to 1, and when it goes down, it just do nothing (or just print a simple text that the down button is pressed).

Comment: Mmh. Are you really sure about that behavior? Do you want to retain the features of QSpinBox (considering that, with that behavior, the remaining features will be the keyboard [Page]Up/[Page]Down events and the input mask? Because if you're not interested in that, you really *don't* need a QSpinBox at all. Maybe, if you clarify your requirements by providing a typical use case scenario, we might be of more help...

Comment: Just to clarify: if you provide the user a control that *looks* like a spinbox but does **not** behave like one, you're not doing a good service to the user from the UX point of view. When a user sees the up/down arrows in an input box that only accepts numbers, (s)he expects that by pressing those buttons the value will increase or decrease. Your proposed behavior is not only very *unintuitive* but also very confusing to the user.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the reply. It's merely a save function inside Maya that increments save file names. Just a bit of context here :) When saving a new file, I just want to up the work number and so on until the 3d model is finished i.e "watch_model_v001_w050.ma". Just building it up all the way until it's finished. The version number increases if there's progress from texturing/look development (I'm talking about CGI stuff). The company I worked for has a save function like this and I'm trying to replicate it for myself. I hope this clarifies it. Thanks for the reply again :D

Comment: To further clarify things up,  it's a naming convention and it goes like this, test_v001_w001, test_v001_w002...test_v001_w045. When i need to up the version it wil be test_v002_w001..test_v002_w012... test_v003_w001 and so on hence why I want the work number to reset to 1. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I think I got what you mean, but still (at least, based on your context) I believe it might still be confusing. If I were you, I'd use separate fields: one for the version and another for the "build". While I can understand the need for a single control for the file name, this kind of behavior can be really confusing (and annoying) and maybe you should think about another way to allow the user to set the version. Just to clarify: does the "w[number]" automatically increase? If that's so, you could just update the prefix/suffix *and* override the `stepEnabled()` function.

Comment: The UI has 2 different spinbox (see image) attached. The w number does not automatically increase. 

>> https://imgur.com/a/Tp1w0hi <<

Comment: Can't you just store the current version number, and connect the `valueChanged` to a function that checks if it's increased from the previous value?

Comment: I already connected the spin box to a function. I can't figure out an if statement that checks if the current value increased or decreased by a certain number. Apologies for a lot of confusions here. Just started learning python.

Comment: Ok, for future reference do know that yours is actually an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your issue is not with the QSpinBox, but with the logic of your interface. Implementing the up/down buttons as you requested will not help you: if the user types/pastes the number (or uses the arrow keys) instead of clicking the spinbox, nothing of what you need would happen. I suggest you to think again about the whole logic, then, if you can't figure it out, create a new question also *providing your attempts* (even if they don't work as expected).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `hitTestComplexControl()` method to know which element was clicked:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox, QStyle, QStyleOptionSpinBox


class SpinBox(QSpinBox):
    upClicked = pyqtSignal()
    downClicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

        opt = QStyleOptionSpinBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)

        control = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(
            QStyle.CC_SpinBox, opt, event.pos(), self
        )
        if control == QStyle.SC_SpinBoxUp:
            self.upClicked.emit()
        elif control == QStyle.SC_SpinBoxDown:
            self.downClicked.emit()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = SpinBox()
    w.upClicked.connect(lambda: print("up"))
    w.downClicked.connect(lambda: print("down"))
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll give this a try. Are there more ways to check the signals for up and down arrows in qspinbox?